# Is there any HTML to WikiText translator?

Tags: html, translation, wiki, wikitext

Is there any HTML to WikiText translator? I need to translate tables with hyperlinks and images inside.

Comment: For which wikitext dialect? MediaWiki as used on Wikipedia or some other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [html2wiki](http://mozile.mozdev.org/0.8/demos/html2wiki.xsl) **xslt** stylesheet. It might inspire you.

Comment: Wery good! +1 ))) But It totally does not work for my TrackWiki =(

Answer (score 3):

I've had great success with [this html2wiki online service](http://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/).  I converted a large sample of HTML to MediaWiki, and it was almost flawless.