# How to convert XML to something else using xslt stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, wiki, translation, wikitext

How to convert XML to  something else using xslt stylesheet?

In C++ C# PHP or ActionScript?

For example I have this  [html2wiki xslt stylesheet](http://mozile.mozdev.org/0.8/demos/html2wiki.xsl) I want to send to my programm my XML (in this case HTML file ) and get back a file (in this case Wiki mark up text )

So How to translate one text file into another text file using XSLT  stylesheet in any language?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, you've been inspired by my answer to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162386/is-there-any-html-to-wikitext-translator/2162443#2162443 . It would have been nice to vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
Load SOURCE file as XML
Load STYLESHEET file as XML
Apply STYLESHEET to SOURCE, generating RESULT
Write RESULT out to file as XML
```

Comment: Yeah, I mean each language provides different methods - but the above pseudocode is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html) and [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/python.html) are my personal choices for this kind of functionality.

---

(Edit)  Here is a simple example of performing a transformation using libxml and libxslt:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import libxml2
import libxslt


def getXSLT(xsl_filename):
    # parse the stylesheet xml file into doc object
    styledoc = libxml2.parseFile(xsl_filename)

    # process the doc object as xslt
    style = libxslt.parseStylesheetDoc(styledoc)

    return style


if __name__ == '__main__':
    style = getXSLT("stylesheet.xsl")
    doc = libxml2.parseFile("data.xml")
    result = style.applyStylesheet(doc, None)

    print result
```

Comment: How to achieve this in python3.4

Answer (score 2):

here is an example using **C** and **libxslt**: http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/tutorial/libxslttutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, you may want to look at [this article](http://www.asp101.com/articles/jayram/xslt/default.asp). In C++, you can use [Xalan-C++](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/). Xalan-C++ even has some [handy examples](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/samples.html) of how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

in PHP take a look at this

[DomXsltStylesheet->process](http://gr.php.net/manual/en/function.domxsltstylesheet-process.php)
and also read the last note at the bottom which has a working example ...

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools has my favorite XSLT tutorial ..

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The correct library in Python now is `lxml`. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python) on StackOverflow. 
It is similar syntax, and you wont have issues in installing it.