# How to Translate XML into HTML using XSL Stylesheet in Python?

Tags: python, html, xml, xslt

I have an XSL stylesheet template that transforms my XML file into HTML. How can I perform such processing using Python?

[...and here's the link to really simple solution:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163024/how-to-convert-xml-to-something-else-using-xslt-stylesheet/2163192#2163192)

Comment: Are you looking for a Python implementation of an XSLT processor, or any kind of bridge to an XSLT processor?

Comment: @Alejandro I'm looking for the most simple way, if there is, to processing my xml files using stylesheet and python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de), which [supports XSLT 1.0](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt).