# XSLT with Python's lxml: Forbidden Variable?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

I'm trying to transform XML to XHTML using XSLT. I'd like to do it using Python, but I'm not particularly attached to any library. Following [the directions here,](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt) I've been trying this:

```
from lxml import etree

xslt_root=etree.parse('editions.xsl')
transform=etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xslt.pxi", line 406, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__init__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136874)
lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Forbidden variable
```

I also tried using [this python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163024/how-to-convert-xml-to-something-else-using-xslt-stylesheet/2163192#2163192), which uses libxslt, but it gives me these errors:

```
    Forbidden variable
compilation error: file editions.xsl line 283 element key
xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//tei:div/tei:ab/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#folger'] |// tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#folger']'
Forbidden variable
compilation error: file editions.xsl line 284 element key
xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//tei:div/tei:ab/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#folger'] |// tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#folger']'
Forbidden variable
compilation error: file editions.xsl line 285 element key
xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//tei:div/tei:ab/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#texta'] |// tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#texta']'
Forbidden variable
compilation error: file editions.xsl line 286 element key
xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//tei:div/tei:ab/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#texta'] |// tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#texta']'
Forbidden variable
compilation error: file editions.xsl line 287 element key
xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//tei:div/tei:ab/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#textb'] |// tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#textb']'
Forbidden variable
compilation error: file editions.xsl line 288 element key
xsl:key : 'match' pattern compilation failed '//tei:div/tei:ab/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#textb'] |// tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]/tei:ptr[@type='emendation'][@ana='#textb']'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transform.py", line 21, in <module>
    result = style.applyStylesheet(doc, None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'applyStylesheet'
```

The XSL file I'm using is [here](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/shakespeare-dialog-extractor/blob/master/editions.xsl). It's professionally created, so I wouldn't think there would be big problems with it.

Is there a way to override this error, so that I can get my XML file to transform in python? Or is there a different way to do this XSLT where I won't be getting errors all the time? Transforming in the browser (Firefox) works fine, but I can't get it to work in Python.

Comment: Additional error detail can be found  `.error_messages`[See: errors-and-message](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid your contractor has let you down. The XSLT specification says this in [section 12.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key):

> It is an error for the value of either the use attribute or the match attribute to contain a VariableReference.

So the `key` elements in lines 283 to 288 of `editions.xsl` are not valid XSLT because their `match` attributes use the path step `tei:rdg[contains(@wit,$rdg)]`.

Fortunately, `$rdg` is a simple constant defined at line 183 to be `'lemma'`, so if you change all six occurrences of this path step to `tei:rdg[contains(@wit,'lemma')]` instead, it should all work for you.

Comment: How did you find that error? Do you know of a useful Validator?

Comment: @MatthewWilcoxson: Well I looked at your Python error log that says there is a `Forbidden variable` error on each line 283 to 288. Then I looked at line 283 of the file to find the forbidden variable. That seems to be all the validation you should need.

Comment: Thanks @Borodin, I hadn't noticed the error output above, was hoping you had use some superduper validator to find it. ;)