# How to transform an XML file using XSLT in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, converters

Good day! Need to convert xml using xslt in Python. I have a sample code in php.

How to implement this in Python or where to find something similar? Thank you!

```
$xmlFileName = dirname(__FILE__)."example.fb2";
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($xmlFileName);

$xslFileName = dirname(__FILE__)."example.xsl";
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load($xslFileName);

// Configure the transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Using [lxml](https://lxml.de/index.html),

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse(xml_filename)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: Hello, I have one more question here. If the xml file is large, the efficiency of "newdom = transform(dom)" is very bad. I tried to parse a large xml file (>100MB), it will cost a long time (>4 hours) to transform. Do you have any good advice about transforming xml file with xslt using python lxml?

Comment: Under the hood, lxml is using [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) to transform the XML. I don't know of anything you can do to speed this up. Maybe if you post your XSLT in a new question, someone will be able to suggest an improvement.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using write with no luck. How do you write contents to file?

Comment: @programiss What you mean with no luck? Etree.write(file, pretty_print) is the method to use. Maybe you passed wrong argument? That's common mistake. It's supposed to be writable object (eg. file or sys.stdout, etc), so not just filename string.

Comment: `print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))` for some reason only showed me part of the expected output (compared with xsltproc). The solution was to use `print(str(newdom))`, as stated [here](https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.XSLT.tostring)

Comment: With Python 3, one has to produce a unicode string when writing to stdout:

`print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode"))`

Comment: XSLT is a stylesheet file I use it with xml in APEX to produce PDF reports. how can I do that in python please !.. 
Thank you in advance @unutbu

Answer (score 6):

[LXML](https://lxml.de/index.html) is a widely used high performance library for XML processing in python based on libxml2 and libxslt - it includes facilities for [XSLT as well](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt).

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to do it using lxml, but it only support XSLT 1

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

inputpath = "D:\\temp\\"
xsltfile = "D:\\temp\\test.xsl"
outpath = "D:\\output"


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename.endswith(('.xml', '.txt')):
                    dom = ET.parse(inputpath + filename)
                    xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
                    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
                    newdom = transform(dom)
                    infile = unicode((ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True)))
                    outfile = open(outpath + "\\" + filename, 'a')
                    outfile.write(infile)
```

to use XSLT 2 you can check options from [Use saxon with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443364/use-saxon-with-python)

Comment: for people using XSLT3.x this is the way!

Comment: Long story short: for XSLT 2 and up, use [SaxonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58448374/1016065).   As @Maliq suggests, lxml does not support any higher than XSLT 1.   In my case, the line `transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)` errors because my `xsltfile` has `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ` in it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787161/1016065).