# Applying XSLT 2.0 transformations with Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt

Im trying to apply the example XSLT transformations provided by the German government for the new XRechnung standard:

https://github.com/itplr-kosit/xrechnung-visualization

I haven't had any luck with lxml because it only supports XSLT 1.0. Is there another Python library I could use (or another approach i could try)?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29443364/407651

Comment: We've got a Python binding for Saxon/C working internally in Saxonica but it's not yet at release status. Feel free to contact us at Saxonica to see whether we can work together on some kind of beta testing basis.

Comment: This was meant to be just a quick test. I don't have time t turn it into a project in its own right. But I'll be looking forward to the relase of the Python version of Saxon.