# Get only last part of xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am using lxml in python 2.7 to parse an xml file.

the file looks like this:

```
...
<LM>sua</LM>
<LM>citt&agrave;</LM>
<LM>e</LM>
<LM>l'</LM>
<LM>alto</LM>
<LM>seggio</LM>:
     </l><l>
<LM>oh</LM>
<LM>felice</LM>
<LM>colui</LM>
<LM>cu'</LM>
<LM>ivi</LM>
<LM>elegge</LM>!.
     </l><l>
<LM> E</LM>
<LM>io</LM>
<LM>a</LM>
<LM>lui</LM>:
...
```

I am iterating through the tree looking for LM nodes.

```
for node in [z for z in  tree.iterfind(".//LM")]:
    print tree.getpath(node.getparent())
```

and  I get the following output for each node:

```
'/TEI.2/text/body/div1/l[480]'
```

So, in this case this means the the current node LM is under the 480th node L. Is there a way to get this 480 that is note the following ?

```
In [77]: int(tree.getpath(node.getparent()).split('/')[5][2:].replace(']',''))
Out[77]: 480
```

I mean an elegant way via xpath.

Comment: `.getpath` is only returning a string, and I don't think lxml provides anything more granular.  If you only cared about the last node you could do this `int(re.search("\[(.*?)]", tree.getelementpath(node.getparent())).groups()[0])` (but this isn't necessarily "better").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, in this case this means the the current node LM is under the 480th node L. Is there a way to get this 480 that is note the following ?
>
> ```
> int(tree.getpath(node.getparent()).split('/')[5][2:].replace(']',''))
> ```

If I understand you correctly, you merely want the position relative to its parent? You can have the XPath return this last position by doing:

```
node.find("position()")
```

In normal XPath 1.0, this means "get the position of the current node relative to its parent". However, it looks like the [XPath support of this Python module is severely limited](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support). The expressions supported can only be used to return a node and not a value.

[If you can use XSLT in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python), you can get all the positions using the XPath 1.0 syntax `//LM/position()`. And to get the path as well, you have to do a bit more:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//LM" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LM">
    <xsl:text>Position: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    <xsl:text>, XPath: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="path" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:template>
```

This will output a bunch of lines like:

```
Position: 4, XPath: /a/b/c
Position: 9, XPath: /a/b/d
```

Comment: I understand. In this case I think I will stick to my sub-optimal solution.

Comment: @Angelo, ok, no problem. Then you will have to loop all nodes by hand and count, as there's no support for the feature yet in Python using the libraries you currently use...