# can I use python to edit xml file based on csv file values?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a CSV file with a list of numbers with gaps in them, like:

```
0001
0002
0003
0005
0007
etc.
```

And I have an XML file with nodes with identifiers with a list of numbers without gaps, like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
    <item>
        <unitd>0001</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 1</unittitle>
    </item>
    <item>
        <unitd>0002</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 2</unittitle>
    </item>
    <item>
        <unitd>0003</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 3</unittitle>
    </item>
    <item>
        <unitd>0004</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 4</unittitle>
    </item>
    <item>
        <unitd>0005</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 5</unittitle>
    </item>
    <item>
        <unitd>0006</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 6</unittitle>
    </item>
    <item>
        <unitd>0007</unitd>
        <unittitle>description of item 7</unittitle>
    </item>
</root>      <!-- added by edit -->
```

I want to add an extra element to the items of the XML file that have identifiers that can be found in the CSV file, like this:

```
<root>
<item>
    <unitd>0001</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 1</unittitle>
    <link>link to extra info on item 1</link>
</item>
<item>
    <unitd>0002</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 2</unittitle>
    <link>link to extra info on item 2</link>
</item>
<item>
    <unitd>0003</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 3</unittitle>
    <link>link to extra info on item 3</link>
</item>
<item>
    <unitd>0004</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 4</unittitle>
</item>
<item>
    <unitd>0005</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 5</unittitle>
    <link>link to extra info on item 5</link>
</item>
<item>
    <unitd>0006</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 6</unittitle>
</item>
<item>
    <unitd>0007</unitd>
    <unittitle>description of item 7</unittitle>
    <link>link to extra info on item 7</link>
</item>
```

Can I do this using python and how or is there a smarter way to take care of this?

Comment: Can *you*? Probably, since you asked this, "no". Can anyone else? Of course. Python is very well suited to this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The smartest way to handle an XML to XML transformation is using XSLT which was designed for *this exact purpose*.

So to transform your source XML to your desired destination XML you can use this XSLT-1.0 script (named `trans.xslt`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version ="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:variable name="additional" select="document('a_link.xml')/LinkMapping" />   <!-- name of helper XML file -->

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" > 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <!-- item transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="item" > 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*" />
            <xsl:if test="$additional/map[@id=current()/unitd]">
                <link>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$additional/map[@id=current()/unitd]/text()" />
                </link>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template requires an additional XML file containing the mapping of the `link`s from the CSV file called `a_link.xml`. Your example of a CSV file does not show any relation like this, but transforming the CSV to something like the below format should be no problem.

```
<LinkMapping>
    <map id="0001">link to extra info on item 1</map>
    <map id="0002">link to extra info on item 2</map>
    <map id="0003">link to extra info on item 3</map>
    <map id="0005">link to extra info on item 5</map>
    <map id="0007">link to extra info on item 7</map>
</LinkMapping>
```

*The output of applying the above XSLT with the XML helper file is as desired.*

---

So to use this with Python, you can refer [to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699042/1305969) which explains how to transform an XML file with XSLT.

Assuming that your XML file is named `input.xml` the code could look like this:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse("input.xml")
xslt = ET.parse("trans.xslt")
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

Now you should have gotten your desired result.

Comment: this is great, works like a charm, thank you so much!