# Parsing xml in python to get all child elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have parsed an XML file to get all its elements. I am getting the following output

```py
[<Element '{urn:mitel:params:xml:ns:yang:vld}vld-list' at 0x0000000003059188>, <Element '{urn:mitel:params:xml:ns:yang:vld}vl-id' at 0x00000000030689F8>, <Element '{urn:mitel:params:xml:ns:yang:vld}descriptor-version' at 0x0000000003068A48>]
```

I need to select the value between } and ' only for each element of the list.

This is my Code till now :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse('UMR_VLD01_OAM_V6-Provider_eth0.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()

# all items
print('\nAll item data:')
for elem in root:  
    all_descendants = list(elem.iter())
    print(all_descendants)
```

How  can i achieve this ?

Comment: Show us a sample input.

Comment: To access the tag name of an `Element` you can use `tag` property. Then you use `rfind` to get the last index of `}` and you take the string from there.

Answer (score 1):

The text in `{}` is the namespace part of the qualified name (`QName`) of the XML element. AFAIK there is no method in `ElementTree` to return only the [local name](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name). So, you have to either

- extract the local part of the name with string handling, as already proposed in a comment to your question,
- use `lxml.etree` instead of `xml.etree.ElementTree` and apply `xpath('local-name()')` on each element,
- or provide an XML source without namespace. You can strip the namespace with XSLT.

So, given this XML input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo xmlns="urn:mitel:params:xml:ns:yang:vld">
    <bar>
        <baz x="1"/>
        <yet>
            <more>
                <nested/>
            </more>
        </yet>
    </bar>
    <bar/>
</foo>
```

You can print a list of the local names only with this variation of your program:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
tree = ET.parse('UMR_VLD01_OAM_V6-Provider_eth0.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()

# all items
print('\nAll item data:')
for elem in root:
    all_descendants = [e.tag.split('}', 1)[1] for e in elem.iter()]
    print(all_descendants)
```

Output:

```
['bar', 'baz', 'yet', 'more', 'nested']
['bar']
```

---

The version with `lxml.etree` and `xpath('local-name()')`  looks like this:

```python
import lxml.etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('UMR_VLD01_OAM_V6-Provider_eth0.xml')  
root = tree.getroot()

# all items
print('\nAll item data:')
for elem in root:
    all_descendants = [e.xpath('local-name()') for e in elem.iter()]
    print(all_descendants)
```

The output is the same as with the string handling version.

---

For stripping the namespace completely from your input, you can apply this XSLT:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then your *original* program outputs:

```
[<Element 'bar' at 0x04583B40>, <Element 'baz' at 0x04583B70>, <Element 'yet' at 0x04583BD0>, <Element 'more' at 0x04583C30>, <Element 'nested' at 0x04583C90>]
[<Element 'bar' at 0x04583CC0>]
```

Now the elements *themselves* do not bear a namespace. So, you don't have to strip it anymore.

You can apply the XSLT with with `xsltproc`, then you don't need to change your program. Alternatively, you can [apply XSLT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16698935/2311167), but this also requires you to use `lxml.etree`. So, the last variation of your program looks like this:

```python
import lxml.etree as ET

tree = ET.parse('UMR_VLD01_OAM_V6-Provider_eth0.xml')  
xslt = ET.parse('stripns.xslt')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
tree = transform(tree)

root = tree.getroot()
# all items
print('\nAll item data:')
for elem in root:
    all_descendants = list(elem.iter())
    print(all_descendants)
```