# Remove xml tag using python if a certain text is found

Tags: python, xml

I need to remove all tags from xml document if a certain text is found.

Example:

```xml
<root-element>
    <tag-name first:line="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name second:line="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name third:line="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name first:line="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name second:line="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
</root-element>
```

So for each `first:line` into the XML document, I want to remove the whole tag.

Comment: How about to use XSLT for the task?

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. It is missing a root element. Please fix it.

Comment: There is one more issue with the XML provided. It is using a namespace **(first:, second:, etc.)** for each attribute. I am not sure if it is a real scenario. It seems like an obfuscated XML. Please edit your question and provide a real XML.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a xml parsing library.

I recommend lxml.

Then to build a xpath selector utilize a function string-length() on the text() property. This way it will select any element with text inside.

```
import lxml.etree as et

tree=et.fromstring(xml)

for bad in tree.xpath("//*[string-length(text()) > 0]"):
  bad.getparent().remove(bad)   

print(et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True))
```

Comment: Thanks João A. Veiga. Where should I put "first:line" in the xpath while iterating?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you're trying to do, would you like to only delete the tags that have the attribute first:line? In that case Xpath would be: //*[string-length(text()) > 0 and @first:line]"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it via XSLT.

The XSLT is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

I modified XML and removed bogus namespaces.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root-element>
    <tag-name firstline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name secondline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name thirdline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name firstline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
    <tag-name secondline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
</root-element>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@firstline]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root-element>
  <tag-name secondline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
  <tag-name thirdline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
  <tag-name secondline="some-value">bla-bla</tag-name>
</root-element>
```

Comment: I have to use Python. The attribute does have :, like for example xml:lang

Comment: Keep using Python, just use it's library to handle XSLT transformation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python