# How can I remove a part of XML file?

Tags: python, xml

I need to remove some parts of a XML file, for example this file:

```
<dict>
    <key>Images</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ImageIndex</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NumberOfROIs</key>
            <integer>42</integer>
            <key>ROIs</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Area</key>
                    <real>0.0</real>
                    <key>Center</key>
                    <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    <key>Dev</key>
                    <real>0.0</real>
                    <key>IndexInImage</key>
                    <integer>0</integer>
                    <key>Max</key>
                    <real>1358</real>
                    <key>Mean</key>
                    <real>1358</real>
                    <key>Min</key>
                    <real>1358</real>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>Calcification</string>
                    <key>NumberOfPoints</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>Point_mm</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Point_px</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(2964.620117, 3427.979980)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Total</key>
                    <real>1358</real>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <integer>19</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Area</key>
                    <real>0.0</real>
                    <key>Center</key>
                    <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    <key>Dev</key>
                    <real>0.0</real>
                    <key>IndexInImage</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>Max</key>
                    <real>1401</real>
                    <key>Mean</key>
                    <real>1401</real>
                    <key>Min</key>
                    <real>1401</real>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>Calcification</string>
                    <key>NumberOfPoints</key>
                    <integer>1</integer>
                    <key>Point_mm</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Point_px</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(2993.159912, 3403.550049)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Total</key>
                    <real>1401</real>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <integer>19</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Area</key>
                    <real>1.3665732145309448</real>
                    <key>Center</key>
                    <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    <key>Dev</key>
                    <real>66.487342834472656</real>
                    <key>IndexInImage</key>
                    <integer>36</integer>
                    <key>Max</key>
                    <real>1836</real>
                    <key>Mean</key>
                    <real>1583.29638671875</real>
                    <key>Min</key>
                    <real>1313</real>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>Mass</string>
                    <key>NumberOfPoints</key>
                    <integer>89</integer>
                    <key>Point_mm</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                        <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Point_px</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(3196.290039, 1048.599976)</string>
                        <string>(3203.560059, 1046.170044)</string>
                        <string>(3211.330078, 1042.780029)</string>
                        <string>(3189.500000, 1050.540039)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Total</key>
                    <real>44457380</real>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <integer>15</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to remove everything between < dict > < /dict >, included, that have a < string > Calcification < /string > in it, in other words, I want only the parts that does not have Calcification, my desired result for this file would be:

```
<dict>
    <key>Images</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>ImageIndex</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>NumberOfROIs</key>
            <integer>42</integer>
            <key>ROIs</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Area</key>
                    <real>1.3665732145309448</real>
                    <key>Center</key>
                    <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    <key>Dev</key>
                    <real>66.487342834472656</real>
                    <key>IndexInImage</key>
                    <integer>36</integer>
                    <key>Max</key>
                    <real>1836</real>
                    <key>Mean</key>
                    <real>1583.29638671875</real>
                    <key>Min</key>
                    <real>1313</real>
                    <key>Name</key>
                    <string>Mass</string>
                    <key>NumberOfPoints</key>
                    <integer>89</integer>
                    <key>Point_mm</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                        <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Point_px</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>(3196.290039, 1048.599976)</string>
                        <string>(3203.560059, 1046.170044)</string>
                        <string>(3211.330078, 1042.780029)</string>
                        <string>(3189.500000, 1050.540039)</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>Total</key>
                    <real>44457380</real>
                    <key>Type</key>
                    <integer>15</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

this is what I have tried:

```
data = r"C:\Users\vinc\Desktop\ExemploXML.xml"    
    
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(data)
root = tree.getroot()
for e in root.findall(".//string"):
    if e.text == 'Calcification':
        
        print(e)
        root.remove(e)
    else:
        pass
tree.write(r'C:\Users\vinc\Desktop\out.xml')
```

Result ======================================

```
<Element 'string' at 0x000002B085002EA0>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-d417d00038ed> in <module>
      8 
      9         print(e)
---> 10         root.remove(e)
     11     else:
     12         pass

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

For context, those XML files are semantic segmentation information, and I want to remove the Calcification class annotations.

Comment: It is very easy to achieve via XSLT. Are you open to it?

Comment: Do you want to remove only dict items that have `<key>Area</key>`?

Comment: Another - very simple - way to do it is by using lxml instead of elementtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: xml.etree.ElementTree - The ElementTree XML API](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree).

I always prefer searching nodes by *XPATH*, and specifying (as much as possible of) the full one. Of course, the drawback is that if the *XML* structure changes, the node paths (in the code) should be adapted accordingly.

Also, as a general pattern (don't know if applies here though), never remove elements from a container you're iterating on.

I saved your source *XML* in *file00.xml* (also removing the last (unmatched) tag (***"</plist>  "***)).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys


def main(*argv):
    xml_file_name = "./file00.xml"
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file_name)
    root = tree.getroot()
    inner_array_nodes = root.findall("./array/dict/array")  # XPATH
    to_remove = []
    for parent_node in inner_array_nodes:
        for dict_node in parent_node:
            string_nodes = dict_node.findall("string")
            for string_node in string_nodes:
                if string_node.text == "Calcification":
                    to_remove.append((parent_node, dict_node))

    for parent, child in to_remove:
        parent.remove(child)

    print(b"".join(ET.tostringlist(root)).decode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070442605]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> <dict>
>     <key>Images</key>
>     <array>
>         <dict>
>             <key>ImageIndex</key>
>             <integer>0</integer>
>             <key>NumberOfROIs</key>
>             <integer>42</integer>
>             <key>ROIs</key>
>             <array>
>                 <dict>
>                     <key>Area</key>
>                     <real>1.3665732145309448</real>
>                     <key>Center</key>
>                     <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
>                     <key>Dev</key>
>                     <real>66.487342834472656</real>
>                     <key>IndexInImage</key>
>                     <integer>36</integer>
>                     <key>Max</key>
>                     <real>1836</real>
>                     <key>Mean</key>
>                     <real>1583.29638671875</real>
>                     <key>Min</key>
>                     <real>1313</real>
>                     <key>Name</key>
>                     <string>Mass</string>
>                     <key>NumberOfPoints</key>
>                     <integer>89</integer>
>                     <key>Point_mm</key>
>                     <array>
>                         <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
>                         <string>(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)</string>
>                     </array>
>                     <key>Point_px</key>
>                     <array>
>                         <string>(3196.290039, 1048.599976)</string>
>                         <string>(3203.560059, 1046.170044)</string>
>                         <string>(3211.330078, 1042.780029)</string>
>                         <string>(3189.500000, 1050.540039)</string>
>                     </array>
>                     <key>Total</key>
>                     <real>44457380</real>
>                     <key>Type</key>
>                     <integer>15</integer>
>                 </dict>
>             </array>
>         </dict>
>     </array>
> </dict>
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Here is XSLT based solution.

The XSLT below is following a so called ***Identity Transform*** pattern.

A single one line template removes not needed `<dict>` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="dict[string='Calcification']"/>
```

[How to transform an XML file using XSLT in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698935/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python)

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dict[string='Calcification']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And in XSLT 3.0 it's even simpler, you can replace the first template rule with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your XML has an extra plist tag.
2. Your code even if it did work is only trying to remove **string** tag which has the "**Calcification**" text in it and not the dict like you tried.
3. I have a working solution here - maybe not the most optimized code but works for sure I just tried it against your input

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
dict_list = []

array = root.find("./array/dict/array")

for each_dict in array.iter('dict'):
    for each_string in each_dict.iter('string'):
        if each_string.text == "Calcification":
            dict_list.append(each_dict)

for each_dict in dict_list:
    array.remove(each_dict)

tree.write('sample3.xml')
```