# split large xml data by python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, split, large-data

I have large xml file and I need to split into smaller size when the tag is comment and has something like case description. I need to do it in python

I have written this to read the large xml file but I don't know how to split it into a new file

```
testCases = []
countr = 0
xml_iter = et.iterparse('Main.xml', events=('start', 'end'))
for  event, elem in xml_iter:
    text = elem.text
    
        # if text not in testCases:
        #     testCases.append(text)
    

    if event == 'start':
        print('<%s>' % elem.tag, end = '')
        
        if text != '':
            print(text, end = '')
               

    elif event == 'end':
        print('<%s>' % elem.tag) 
    if text != None and "comment" in elem.tag and "#Test Case ID:" in text:
        break
```

Comment: Please share an example xml and your expected output.

Comment: And where you will keep the spitted file and for what purpose ? There is something called `xslt` that is designed to work with xml. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699042/3057246

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question rigth, the easiest solution would probably be something like this:

```
splitfile = open( name + ".xml", "w" )
```

*name* should be a unique string for that part of the original file.
*"w"* says you want to write to the file. If the file doesn't exist, it is created, but if it exist, it will be **overwritten**, so choose a good namestring (maybe your Test case ID?).

In the open file you now can:

```
splitfile.write( text )
```

When you're done with that file make sure to

```
splitfile.close()
```

So you can do it something like this:

```
if text != None and "comment" in elem.tag and "#Test Case ID:" in text:  `
    splitfile = open( str(countr)+ ".xml", "w" )
    countr++
    ...
    splitfile.write(text)
    ...
    splitfile.close()
```

You can see that my filename is not very good, but you can choose a fitting one.

Your new files will be created in the same directory as your python script.