# how to get the xml tag name after parsing as it is specified in xml without namespace conversion

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I need to parse xml into another structure.
example:
`a = """`
`<actors xmlns:fictional="http://characters.example.com">`
 `<actor>`    
    `<name>Eric Idle</name>`
     `<fictional:character>Sir Robin</fictional:character>`
     `<fictional:character>Gunther</fictional:character>`
     `<fictional:character>Commander Clement</fictional:character>`
   `</actor>`
`</actors>`
`"""`

I am using ElementTree to parse the tree
`root = ElementTree.fromstring(a)`

When I apply
`root[0][1].tag`

I get the result
``` {``http://characters.example.com``}character ```

but I need to get the result as it was in the original file
`fictional:character`

how do I achieve this result?

Comment: It's pretty simple if you can use lxml.

Comment: could you share your disired output?
[Using xslt in python could be the easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16699042/3710053)

Answer (score 1):

With XPath, you can return namespace prefixes with local name of an element using `name()` (and without prefix: `local-name()`). Python's third-party package, `lxml`, can run XPath 1.0:

```py
import lxml.etree as lx

a = """
<actors xmlns:fictional="http://characters.example.com">
 <actor>    
    <name>Eric Idle</name>
     <fictional:character>Sir Robin</fictional:character>
     <fictional:character>Gunther</fictional:character>
     <fictional:character>Commander Clement</fictional:character>
   </actor>
</actors>
"""

root = xl.fromstring(a)

for el in root.xpath("/actor/*"):
   print(el.xpath("name()"))

# name
# fictional:character
# fictional:character
# fictional:character
```

Answer (score 0):

with ElementTree library there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: this option returns {`http://characters.example.com`}character

Comment: sorry i think i made a mistake. is ElementTree a requirement or you can use other libs?

Comment: there are others, I looked at lxml, bs4, they don't do what I need

Answer (score 0):

You can use re.sub():

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
from io import StringIO

a = """
<actors xmlns:fictional="http://characters.example.com">
 <actor>    
    <name>Eric Idle</name>
     <fictional:character>Sir Robin</fictional:character>
     <fictional:character>Gunther</fictional:character>
     <fictional:character>Commander Clement</fictional:character>
   </actor>
</actors>
"""
f = StringIO(a)

tree = ET.parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()

ns={"fictional": "http://characters.example.com"}

for elem in root.findall(".//fictional:character", ns):
    print(re.sub("{http://characters.example.com}", "fictional:", elem.tag), elem.text)
```

Output:

```
fictional:character Sir Robin
fictional:character Gunther
fictional:character Commander Clement
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `expat parser` is engaged in the transformation of namespaces.
It is created by the parser, which is used by default `ElementTree`.

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser
```

is created in the initialization method with the command

```
parser = expat.ParserCreate(encoding, "}")
```

You can override the standard behavior of the parser if you redefine this line to

```
parser = expat.ParserCreate(encoding, None)
```

In this case, namespace processing is disabled